# Is there a way to assign pyarrow schema to the RECORD data type in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery, apache-beam, pyarrow

The goal of my Apache Beam pipeline is to take data from a table in BigQuery and then output it into a parquet file.

I am trying to use the [WriteToParquet](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.11.0/apache_beam.io.parquetio.html#apache_beam.io.parquetio.WriteToParquet) `PTransform` in my Apache Beam pipeline, which requires the `schema` to be passed as a `pyarrow.Schema`.

This part of my code maps different types of schema from BigQuery to various `pyarrow` schema:

```
data_type_mapping = {
    'STRING': pyarrow.string(),
    'BYTES': pyarrow.string(),
    'INTEGER': pyarrow.int64(),
    'INT64': pyarrow.int64(),
    'FLOAT64': pyarrow.float64(),
    'FLOAT': pyarrow.float64(),
    'BOOLEAN': pyarrow.bool_(),
    'TIMESTAMP': pyarrow.timestamp(unit='ms'),
    'DATE': pyarrow.date32(),
    'DATETIME': pyarrow.string()
}
```

The problem is that there is a data type in BigQuery, `RECORD`, and I do not know how to map it to the correct `pyarrow` schema.

[These](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/api/datatypes.html) are the various available data types. Which one can I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would probably want to use as [pyarrow.struct](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.struct.html#pyarrow.struct) for this.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I'm currently trying out now (didn't want to post until I verified that it works). I'm currently struggling most with nested `struct`s. I.e. if a `RECORD` contains another `RECORD`... I've come up with a recursive algorithm to generate schema for this, but I'm getting the following error: 

`pyarrow.lib.ArrowTypeError: Expected a string or bytes object, got a 'list' object`.

I'll post something once I figure it out :)

Comment: The data that I was trying to pull from that yielded the error message in the previous comment contained `ARRAY`s, which I failed to account for. Is the equivalent for `BigQuery` `ARRAY` type `pyarrow.list_`? It's the closest matching one I could find.

Comment: Yes, that looks like the best mapping.